# Query to search patients

Tags: java

I'm creating a simple health system database and I want to be able to create a query that searches the patients already in the database. I have a text field where I enter the patient's first and last name and it should print to the console the patients ID number , first name , last name, and the type of services they need. When I try using a button to query the results I get a java.lang.NullPointerException. Is this because I only take the first, and last name as my query or for another reason.

Connection and serachPatient methods:

```
    public void serachPatient() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.println("Preparing a statement...");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        
        String sql = "SELECT fname, lname FROM Services";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        
        while(rs.next()) {
            //Retrieve by column name
            int id = rs.getInt("paitinet_id");
            String firstName = rs.getString("fname");
            String lastName = rs.getString("lname");
            String serviceType = rs.getString("service_type");
            
            //Display values
            System.out.print("ID: " + id);
            System.out.print("First Name: " + firstName);
            System.out.print("Last Name: " + lastName);
            System.out.print("Service Type: " + serviceType);
        }
        rs.close();
    }catch(SQLException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        if(stmt!=null)
            conn.close();
    }catch(SQLException se) {
        
    }
    
}
```

Search Button Action:

```
//Create "Search" event
    search.setOnAction(e->{
        try {
            serachPatient();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

Comment: you call `conn.createStatement()` but you never instantiated `conn`, hence the NullPointerException. So add something like `conn=DriverManager.getConnection(  
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb","root","root");`

Comment: @Conffusion thank you I appreciate the helpful solution. Althoguh now when I search the patient the program prints all of the patients in the database instead of the ones I search with the button.

Comment: Off course. your query is `SELECT fname, lname FROM Services`. You should add a `WHERE`clause using the values entered by the user.

Comment: @Conffusion this solution worked, thank you it was very helpful.